# File reading from AMQ

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, apache-camel

Hi folks I am creating a consumer and producer using AMQ. Now the point is i am reading a file (it would be a xml , csv or simple text file) from camel and send to a AMQ topic and now the problem is that when another consumer want to read that file so how can I read this file (xml , txt or csv) for that consumer. I solve it by removing camel from the architecture and converting file into byte and then send ByteMessage on topic.
But I want to know is there any other way to do this? what should I do if I still want to use camel as it release a lot of efforts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly.
But you want to Read a file, send it to AMQ. 
    from("file:/etc/myfiles").to("jms:topic:mytopic"); or similar?

But then you want to keep the file around, if another application should be interested in it.

Camel offers multiple choices for avoiding reading files that have been transfered already. delete=true for removal, moving into a local .camel directory etc.

There is very good documentation at the Camel website. 
http://camel.apache.org/file2

You should probably elaborate a bit more for a more accurate answer.

Comment: exactly some how you got my problem - now the remaining thing is ("file:/etc/myfiles").to("jms:topic:mytopic"); -> when i put it to mytopic -> now i want to place these files into another folder from "mytopics" -- i dont it is right or wrong but i want to do this 1) ("file:/etc/myfiles1").to("jms:topic:mytopic"); and then 2) ("jms:topic:mytopic").to("file:/etc/myfiles2"); -- is it possible